# Rails form preview page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to save the Job data in the database, and redirect to a preview page (instead of the `show` page) which displays all the information from the Job form just submitted (essentially a duplicate of the `show.html.erb` page).

Currently, when the user submits the form (without errors), the Job is created with status 'Paused'. And the user is redirected to the `preview` page. But I am having trouble displaying the Job information, I get a `Couldn't find Job without an ID` error.

I have also tried passing in the `@job.id` using `<%= f.hidden_field :job_id, value: @job.id %>` in `jobs/_form.html.erb` but I get this error: `Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Job: job_id`

controllers/jobs_controller.rb

```
def create
  userprofile = current_user.userprofile

  @job = userprofile.jobs.build(params[:job])
  @job.status = 'Paused'
  @job.audit_status = 'Approved'

  respond_to do |format|
    if @job.save
      format.html {redirect_to preview_path, notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @job, status: :created, location: @job }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end


def preview 
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. Pass `id` as an url param for `preview_path`:

```
if @job.save
  format.html {redirect_to preview_path(id: @job.id), notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
  # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't pass the @job object with the redirect:

```
 redirect_to preview_path(@job)
```